# Another attempt of "real private" methods in JS

Tags: javascript

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/rabbit_aaron/ve7deecw/

This is again, a JUST FOR FUN project. In this attempt, I use a closure instead of validating caller to ensure only member methods can access private methods.

Pros:

- Easy to implement
- Works in strict mode
- All class instances has the same private methods
- Yes, real private, private methods is not accessible from outside, since it is within a closure.

Cons:

- It changes your public method body
- The use of Function constructor makes JSHint unhappy

***What are the other cons of this attempt?***

Code also pasted here:

```
var Class = (function () {
    'use strict';
    /*
     * find all pairs of parentheses' begin and end position
     * return an object containing all levels of parentheses
     * (this function is unused)
     */
    function findParentheses(str) {
        var results = {};
        var level = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            if (str[i] == '(') {
                ++level;
                results[level] = results[level] || [];
                results[level].push(i);
            } else if (str[i] == ')') {
                results[level].push({
                    begin: results[level].pop(),
                    end: i
                });
                --level;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
    /*
     * Name of your class should be specified in the constructor
     * e.g. new Class(function MyClass(){});
     */
    var Class = function (constructor) {
        if (!constructor.name) {
            throw 'Please name your class';
        }
        this.constructor = constructor;
        this.staticMethods = {};
        this.publicMethods = {};
        this.privateMethods = {};
    };

    /*
     * Return the first matching parentheses indexes.
     */
    function findParenthesis(str, start) {
        var count = 0;
        var started = false;
        var result = [];
        for (var i = start || 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            if (str[i] == '(') {
                ++count;
                started = true;
                result.push(i);
            } else if (str[i] == ')') {
                --count;
                if (count === 0 && started) {
                    result.push(i);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * replace a part of a string with specified replacement snipet, 
     * from index start to end
     */
    function replaceString(str, replacement, start, end) {
        return str.substring(0, start) + replacement + str.substring(end, str.length);
    }
    /*
     * this function replace this.privateMethod to __private__.privateMethod.call(this)
     * the private methods in the new context would be defined in a closure,
     * hidden from the outside, hence private methods are "real private"
     */
    function replacePrivateMethodCalls(funcStr, callRegExp) {
        var start = 0;
        while ((start = funcStr.search(callRegExp)) !== -1) {
            var funcName = funcStr.match(callRegExp)[1];
            var pos = findParenthesis(funcStr, start);
            var args = funcStr.substring(pos[0] + 1, pos[1]);
            if(args.trim().length){
                args = ',' + args;
            }
            var replacement = '__private__.' + funcName + '.call(this' + args;
            funcStr = replaceString(funcStr, replacement, start, pos[1]);
        }
        return funcStr;
    }

    function processPrivateMethodCall(funcStr) {
        var nameRegExp = '(';
        for (var i in this.privateMethods) {
            nameRegExp += this.privateMethods[i].name + '|';
        }
        nameRegExp = nameRegExp.substring(0, nameRegExp.length - 1) + ')';
        var funcCallRegExp = 'this\\s*\\.\\s*' + nameRegExp + '\\s*\\(';
        var regExp = new RegExp(funcCallRegExp);
        return replacePrivateMethodCalls(funcStr,regExp);
    }

    Class.prototype.finalize = function () {
        // beginning of closure
        var funcStr = 'return (function(){\n';
        // private namespace __private__, and yes, I am a python programmer
        funcStr += 'var __private__ = {};\n';
        // define private methods in a closure, in the namespace __private__
        for (var i in this.privateMethods) {
            funcStr += '__private__.' + this.privateMethods[i].name + ' = ' + this.privateMethods[i].toString() + ';\n';
        }
        // define the "class" constructor
        funcStr += this.constructor.toString() + ';\n';
        // attach all public methods, these methods need access to the private methods,
        // hence they need to be defined in this closure
        for (i in this.publicMethods) {
            funcStr += this.constructor.name + '.prototype.' + this.publicMethods[i].name + ' = ' + this.publicMethods[i].toString() + ';\n';
        }
        // return the class to outside world
        funcStr += 'return ' + this.constructor.name + ';\n';
        // end of closure
        funcStr += '})();';
        funcStr = processPrivateMethodCall.call(this, funcStr);
        // evil "eval"!
        var newClass = new Function(funcStr);
        newClass = newClass();
        // attach static methods,
        // static methods has no access to private methods
        for (i in this.staticMethods) {
            newClass[i] = this.staticMethods[i];
        }
        // register the class, might not be necessary
        Class.classes[constructor.name] = newClass;
        return newClass;
    };
    Class.prototype.ensureDistinct = function(funcName){
        if(this.publicMethods[funcName]){
            throw 'Public method with name ' + funcName + ' already exist!';
        }
        if(this.privateMethods[funcName]){
            throw 'Private method with name ' + funcName + ' already exist!';
        }
    };
    Class.prototype.addStaticMethod = function (method) {
        if (!method.name) {
            throw 'Please name your method';
        }
        this.staticMethods[method.name] = method;
    };

    Class.prototype.addPublicMethod = function (method) {
        if (!method.name) {
            throw 'Please name your method';
        }
        this.ensureDistinct(method.name);
        this.publicMethods[method.name] = method;
    };

    Class.prototype.addPrivateMethod = function (method) {
        if (!method.name) {
            throw 'Please name your method';
        }
        this.ensureDistinct(method.name);
        this.privateMethods[method.name] = method;
    };

    Class.classes = {};

    return Class;
})();
```

I have a previous attempt here: [One attempt of private methods in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303961/one-attempt-of-private-methods-in-js)

Comment: It won't work in the wild, as 1) not all engines support function `.name`s 2) not all engines support function decompilation 3) your regexes will match and replace false positives.

Comment: @Bergi Can you elaborate your point 3) ?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool to process a non-regular language like JavaScript. It'll match some things that are no function calls. Better use a parser like esprima and operate on the AST (if you want to do this seriously).

Comment: Oh, and your regex won't catch something like `var self = this; self.privateMethod()`. Though you probably never can reliably without writing a complete compiler.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I believe you're right, what if instead of replacing the function string, I just let you do `__private__.method.call(this,arg1,arg2...)` when you want to call your private methods?

Comment: Sure, one can always do that, but one won't need your framework any more then :-)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Your post looks good (it came up in the First Post review queue), hope you get good answers!

Comment: @Bergi why are your comments not an answer? To me they definitely look like a fragmented answer

Comment: @Vogel612: They're not exhaustive :-) And initially, it was supposed to be only one non-extensive comment…

Comment: I posted an answer, but I deleted it for now, as I'm not sure I covered some cases.